# Jquery load function not working this way

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I tried to do this but seems that is not working :

```
$("#tecnicotabela").load(window.location + " #tecnicotabela");
```

This is not the same thing as doing this:

```
var blabla='"#tecnicotabela"';
$(blabla).load(window.location + " #tecnicotabela");
```

There is any way to put this working? basically it does nothing right now

Comment: You need to define `blabla` properly i.e. `'#tecnicotabela'` either use single or double quotes not both

Comment: You're trying to load a div from the page that's already loaded...?

Comment: @Satpal Thanks! That was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

[window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) is an object so use `window.location.href` instead of `window.location` and remove double quotes from your id string,

```
var blabla='#tecnicotabela'; //remove double qoutes from string
$(blabla).load(window.location.href + " #tecnicotabela");
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is that with the variable it dont work, but with the text works, it's to reload a ajax table

Answer (score 0):

you can user location.pathname so your code will be :

```
 var blabla='#tecnicotabela'; //remove double qoutes from string
 $(blabla).load(window.location.href + " #tecnicotabela");
```

Comment: How i can put that variable again after the plus(+)?  Like $(blabla).load(window.location.href + blabla);

Comment: you can use *concat* : *$(blabla).load(window.location.href.concat(blabla));*